# Pigeonhole proof without decidable equality or excluded middle

Tags: coq

In Software Foundations [`IndProp.v`](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/IndProp.html#lab244) one is asked to prove the **pigeonhole principle**, and one may use *excluded middle*, but it is mentioned that it is not strictly necessary.  I've been trying to prove it without EM, but my brain seems to be wired classically.

Q: How would one prove the theorem *without* using excluded middle?  How should one generally approach proofs for types without decidable equality, where one can't easily reason by cases?

I'd be very happy for a complete proof to look at, but please avoid posting it "in the clear", so as to not spoil the exercise in the Software Foundations course.

The definition uses two inductive predicates, `In` and  `repeats`.

```
Require Import Lists.List.
Import ListNotations.

Section Pigeon.

  Variable (X:Type).
  Implicit Type (x:X).

  Fixpoint In x l : Prop :=                        (***    In       ***)
    match l with
    | nil => False
    | (x'::l') => x' = x \/ In x l'
    end.

  Hypothesis in_split : forall x l, In x l ->  exists l1 l2, l = l1 ++ x :: l2.
  Hypothesis in_app:    forall x l1 l2, In x (l1++l2) <-> In x l1 \/ In x l2.

  Inductive repeats : list X -> Prop :=            (***    repeats   ***)
    repeats_hd l x : In x l    -> repeats (x::l)
  | repeats_tl l x : repeats l -> repeats (x::l).

  Theorem pigeonhole_principle_NO_EM:              (***   pigeonhole   ***)
    forall l1  l2,
      length l2 < length l1 ->            (* There are more pigeons than nests *)
      (forall x, In x l1 -> In x l2) ->   (* All pigeons are in some nest *)
      repeats l1.                         (* Thus, some pigeons share nest *)
  Proof.

    (* ??? *)
```

Comment: The trick is that equality of *membership proofs* is still decidable.

Comment: Thanks, could you give an example?

Comment: Cf. [this proof in Agda](https://github.com/gallais/potpourri/blob/master/agda/poc/PigeonHole.agda) for instance.

Comment: Thanks @gallais. On lines 23-24 Agda considers the two cases that could have produced `pr`, either the constructor `here!` or `there`.  How would one do that in Coq? (When I do i.e. `inversion pr` I don't get any information about which constructor was used to construct `pr`, see https://x80.org/collacoq/agikoxayom.coq)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll describe the thought process that led me to a solution, in case it helps. We may apply induction and it is straightforward to reduce to the case `l1 = a::l1'`, `l2 = a::l2'`. Now `l1'` is a subset of `a::l2'`. My EM-trained intuition is that one of the following holds:

- `a` is in `l1'`.
- `a` is not in `l1'`.

In the latter case, each element of `l1'` is in `a::l2'` but differs from `a`, and therefore must be in `l2'`. Thus `l1'` is a subset of `l2'`, and we can apply the inductive hypothesis.

Unfortunately if `In` is not decidable, the above can't be directly formalized. In particular if equality is not decidable for the given type, it's difficult to prove elements are unequal, and therefore difficult to prove a negative statement like `~(In a l1')`. However, we wanted to use that negative statement to prove a positive one, namely

```
forall x, In x l1' -> In x l2'
```

By analogy, suppose we wanted to prove

```
P \/ Q
Q -> R
------
P \/ R
```

The above intuitive argument is like starting from `P \/ ~P`, and using `~P -> Q -> R` in the second case. We can use a direct proof to avoid EM.

Quantifying over the list `l1'` makes this a bit more complicated, but still we can construct a direct proof using the following lemma, which can be proven by induction.

```
Lemma split_or {X} (l : list X) (P Q : X -> Prop) :
  (forall x, In x l -> (P x \/ Q x)) ->
  (exists x, In x l /\ P x) \/ (forall x, In x l -> Q x).
```

---

Finally note that the intuitive pigeonhole principle could also be formalized as the following way, which cannot be proven when the type has undecidable equality (note that it has a negative statement in the conclusion):

```
Definition pigeon2 {X} : Prop := forall (l1 l2 : list X),
  length l2 < length l1 ->
  (exists x, In x l1 /\ ~(In x l2)) \/ repeats l1.
```

Answer (score 3):

A possible constructive proof goes like this:

We prove `pigeonhole_principle_NO_EM` by induction on `l1`. Only the non-empty case is possible because of the length constraint. So, assume `l1 = x :: l1'`. Now, check whether there is some element of `l1'` which is mapped by `f : (forall x, In x l1 -> In x l2)` to the same membership proof as `x`. If there is such an `x'` element, then it follows that `x = x'`, therefore `l1` repeats. If there is no such element, then we can get `l2'` by removing the element that `x` is mapped to from `l2`, and apply the induction hypothesis to `l2'` and the appropriate `f' : forall x, In x l1' -> In x l2'` function.

That's it, but I note that actually formalizing this proof is not easy with the definitions given, because we need to prove heterogeneous or dependent equalities, since we have to compare membership proofs for possibly different elements.

As to the question of getting the hang of constructive proofs in general, an important skill or habit is always examining what kind of data we have, not just what kind of logical facts we know. In this case, membership proofs are actually indices pointing into lists, bundled together with proofs that the pointed-to elements equal certain values. If membership proofs didn't tell where exactly elements are located then this proof would not be possible constructively.

Comment: I follow what you mean (it is quite similar to the EM proof's structure), except for how to `check whether there is some element of l1' which is mapped by f : (forall x, In x l1 -> In x l2) to the same membership proof as x.` Sorry for being so slow...

Comment: Perhaps a stupid question, but won't membership proofs of `In x L` and `In x' L`  be different if the first one contains "`x` is at index 3 in the list" and the other one contains "`x'` is at index 8", even if  `x=x'`?

Comment: To the first question: iterate through the list and decide for each element whether it's mapped to the same index as `x`. You first have to implement dec. equality of membership proofs by induction on them, then implement this check by induction on lists. To the second: if `In x L` and `In y L` point to the same index, then `x = y`. We don't decide anything about equalities of elements, we decide equality of indices, which implies equality of elements.

Comment: `You first have to implement dec. equality of membership proofs by induction on them `  -- Do you mean I should prove i.e. `Lemma in_proof_dec: forall l x (p q: In x l), {p=q} + {p<>q}.`  Could you show how to do this, please? (Here `In` is unfortunately a function and not an inductive predicate, so I need to compare functions, which I can't, without assuming functional extensionality)

Comment: @larsr We'd like to decide [heterogeneous](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Logic.JMeq.html) equality of `In x l` and `In y l`. That's done by induction on `l` if `In` is recursively defined on `l`. Unfortunately I don't have immediately deployable Coq skills, so I can't write example code. You can look at the link in gallais' comment. He does a great job doing a simple proof in Agda, and he also avoids heterogeneous `In` equalities. You can certainly understand the types of the lemmas there even if you don't know Agda.