# Equality between functional and inductive definitions

Tags: coq

I have an inductive definition of the proposition `P` (or `repeats l`) that *a lists contains repeating elements*, and a functional definition of it's negation `Q` (or `no_repeats l`).

I want to show that `P <-> ~ Q`  and `~ P <-> Q`.  I have been able to show three of the four implications, but `~ Q -> P` seems to be different, because I'm unable to extract data from `~Q`.

```
Require Import List.
Variable A : Type.

Inductive repeats : list A -> Prop :=            (*   repeats  *)
  repeats_hd l x : In x l    -> repeats (x::l)
| repeats_tl l x : repeats l -> repeats (x::l).

Fixpoint no_repeats (l: list A): Prop :=
  match l with nil => True | a::l' =>  ~ In a l' /\ no_repeats l' end.

Lemma not_no_repeats_repeats: forall l, (~ no_repeats l) -> repeats l.
  induction l; simpl. tauto. intros.
```

After doing induction on `l`, the second case is

```
  IHl : ~ no_repeats l -> repeats l
  H : ~ (~ In a l /\ no_repeats l)
  ============================
  repeats (a :: l)
```

Is it possible to deduce `In a l \/ ~ no_repeats l` (which is sufficient) from this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your statement implies that equality on `A` supports double negation elimination:

```
Require Import List.
Import ListNotations.

Variable A : Type.

Inductive repeats : list A -> Prop :=            (*   repeats  *)
  repeats_hd l x : In x l    -> repeats (x::l)
| repeats_tl l x : repeats l -> repeats (x::l).

Fixpoint no_repeats (l: list A): Prop :=
  match l with nil => True | a::l' =>  ~ In a l' /\ no_repeats l' end.

Hypothesis not_no_repeats_repeats: forall l, (~ no_repeats l) -> repeats l.

Lemma eq_nn_elim (a b : A) : ~ a <> b -> a = b.
Proof.
  intros H.
  assert (H' : ~ no_repeats [a; b]).
  { simpl. intuition. }
  apply not_no_repeats_repeats in H'.
  inversion H'; subst.
  { subst. simpl in *. intuition; tauto. }
  inversion H1; simpl in *; subst; intuition.
  inversion H2.
Qed.
```

Not every type supports `eq_nn_elim`, which means that you can only prove `not_no_repeats_repeats` by placing additional hypotheses on `A`.  It should suffice to assume that `A` has decidable equality; that is:

```
Hypothesis eq_dec a b : a = b \/ a <> b.
```

Comment: So the functional definition allows one to deduce more things, i.e. makes stronger assumptions about `A`.  I'm transcribing a proof [1] that uses `no_repeats` into using `repeats`, but this must mean that I can't use that proof as a template.  From what I gather [2], it *should* be possible to do it using `repeats`.  [1: https://gist.github.com/AndrasKovacs/071ea86702732dc25ba6] [2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42585024/pigeonhole-proof-without-decidable-equality-or-excluded-middle/47665411#47665411]

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean, but note that it is possible to show `forall l, ~ repeats l <-> no_repeats l`. So you should be able to use the _negation_ of `repeats` in your proof.

Comment: Or... actually, I proved `... -> ~ (~ repeats xs)`, but I can't go from there to `repeats xs`, can I?

Comment: Sorry, that was my fault... I didn't see that the conclusion mentioned no_repeats! Indeed, you cannot go from the double negation to plain repeats...