# Surprising implicit assumptions in intuitionistic definitions

Tags: coq

I'm trying to make sense of something that surprised me.  Consider the following two definitions.

```
Require Import List.
Variable A:Type.

Inductive NoDup : list A -> Prop :=
  NoDup_nil : NoDup nil
| NoDup_cons : forall x l, ~ In x l -> NoDup l -> NoDup (x :: l).

Inductive Dup : list A -> Prop :=
  Dup_hd : forall x l, In x l -> Dup (x :: l)
| Dup_tl : forall x l, Dup l  -> Dup (x :: l).
```

My first intuition was that they say the same thing (but negated).  However, [@Arthur Azevedo De Amorim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47700480/304284) showed that they are not exactly equivalent ([or see here](https://gist.github.com/larsr/c085274d9dff334c29fdaf32e4083e3f)). If `~ NoDup l -> Dup l` then it must be the case that `forall (a b:A), ~ a <> b -> a = b`.  Thus, an extra assumption on the type `A` sneaks in if one uses `~ NoDup` rather than `Dup` when stating one's proof goal.

I tried to spot where this extra assumption is introduced, to get a mental model of what happened, so I will see it myself next time.  My current explanation is that

- it is the `~ In x l` argument to `NoDup_cons` that is responsible, because
- `~ In x l` terms can only be created if one can prove that a certain `x` is *different* from the first element in the list, the second element in the list, etc.

So when I destruct a term om type `NoDup (_::_)` I get a term `~ In _ _` that can only have been created for a type `A` for which  `~ a <> b -> a = b` must hold.

Q: is that  an ok 'informal' way to think about it, or is there a better way to understand it, so I don't fall into that trap again?

Also, I found that the [Coq library contains `NoDup`](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Lists.List.html#NoDup) and not `Dup`, so perhaps some lemmas are weaker than they need to be, because they were formulated using `NoDup` instead of `Dup`. However, they could be formulated with `Dup` because `~Dup l -> NoDup l`.

Comment: Well, it *is* true that `NoDup l` is equivalent to `~ Dup l` - it's just that `Dup l` is not a normal proposition in general, so `~ NoDup l <-> ~~ Dup l` is not equivalent to `Dup l`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the lesson to take out of this example is that you need to be more careful when thinking about negations in intuitionistic logic.  In particular, your statement "they say the same thing (but negated)" makes sense in classical logic: it means either of the equivalent statements `P <-> ~Q` or `~P <-> Q`.  However, in intuitionistic logic these two statements are *not* equivalent, so you would have to be more specific about which of these two (if either) is actually true.

In this case, it *is* true that `NoDup l` is equivalent to `~ Dup l`.  What is *not* true in general is that `Dup l` is a normal proposition (recall that a proposition `P` is called normal if `~~P -> P`, in which case it's easy to conclude that `P <-> ~~P`).  Therefore, `~ NoDup l` is equivalent to `~~ Dup l`, which in general is a strictly weaker statement than `Dup l`.

One possible way to think about the difference between the two is: from a concrete proof of `Dup l`, it would be possible to extract a pair of indices such that the corresponding entries of `l` are equal (not literally as a function in Coq due to the restrictions on eliminating from `Prop` to `Type`, but you could definitely prove a lemma that there exists such a pair of indices).  On the other hand, a concrete proof of `~ NoDup l` simply gives a way to take a purported proof of `NoDup l` and derive a contradiction from it - from which you can't necessarily extract any particular pair of indices.

(I do agree it's somewhat odd that the standard library has only `NoDup` and not `Dup`.)